# Bazel Change Image Base from JDK 11 to JDK 8

Tags: java, bazel

I'm trying to build a custom docker image using bazel for [buildfarm](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-buildfarm). I'm still fairly new to Bazel, so a lot of things from docker to bazel is confusing to me.

Due to certain errors I'm trying to fix, I would like my base image running JDK 8, rather than JDK 11. I assume

```
base = "@java_image_base//image"
```

is somewhat analogous to something like:

```
FROM openjdk:11
```

in Dockerfiles. However, I would like to use a base image of JDK 8. How could I go about doing this?

The bazel target in my `BUILD` file I am trying to build is:

```
container_image(
    name = "server.container",
    base = "@java_image_base//image",
    cmd = [
        "buildfarm-server_deploy.jar",
        "/config/server.config",
        "--port",
        "8980",
    ],
    # leverage the implicit target of the buildfarm-server to get a fat jar.
    # this is simply a workaround for the fact that we have so many dependencies,
    # so we'd want some wrappy script. This seemed more straightforward.
    # https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/java.html#java_binary_implicit_outputs
    files = [
        ":buildfarm-server_deploy.jar",
    ],
    tags = ["container"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

**Followup question:**
How could I look up other base images for bazel `container_image` targets in general? Is there something analogous to Dockerhub but for bazel base images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `base` in `container_image` must be a Bazel target that represents the image, i.e.:

- an image build locally with other Bazel rules
- an image imported with `container_import` from a local tarball
- an image pulled from a remote Docker repository using `container_pull`

If you are looking for a simple replacement of `FROM`, then you probably want to pull the right image in your `WORKSPACE` using `container_pull` and use that as base.